# Add File Uploader to Joomla Admin Component

Tags: php, xml, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5

I made Joomla admin component according to Joomla guide - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component

In that i need to have file uploader which let user to upload single file.

In administrator\components\com_invoicemanager\models\forms\invoicemanager.xml i have defined

```
<field name="invoice" type="file"/>
```

In the controller administrator\components\com_invoicemanager\controllers\invoicemanager.php im trying to retrieve that file like below. But its not working (can't retrieve file)

Where am i doing it wrong ?

How can i get file and save it on disk ?

```
class InvoiceManagerControllerInvoiceManager extends JControllerForm
{
    function save(){
        $file = JRequest::getVar( 'invoice', '', 'files', 'array' );
        var_dump($file);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make sure that you have included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form that the file is being submitting. This is a common mistake

```
/// Get the file data array from the request.
$file = JRequest::getVar( 'Filedata', '', 'files', 'array' ); 

/// Make the file name safe.
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$file['name'] = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

/// Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
if (isset( $file['name'] )) {

/// Make sure that the full file path is safe.
$filepath = JPath::clean( $somepath.'/'.strtolower( $file['name'] ) );

/// Move the uploaded file.
JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name'], $filepath );}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dasun. Getting file data should be like this.

$file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');

Comment: plus if you read the joomla docs you will find the same code there :-)

Comment: Great answer. JRequest is deprecated though. You should use JFactory::getApplication()->input->get() instead

Comment: @SørenBeckJensen's comment is slightly incorrect. The proper replacement is `$file = JFactory::getApplication()->input->files->get('jform');`. More info can be found in the [documentation for JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput#Retrieving_File_Data).

Answer (score 1):

Think i found the solution :)

```
$file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
```

Saving part is mentioned here - http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines

Answer (score 1):

For uploading the file from your component, you need to write your code in the controller file and you can extend the save() method. check the code given below -

```
public function save($data = array(), $key = 'id')
{
    // Neccesary libraries and variables
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

    //Debugging
    ini_set("display_error" , 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Get input object
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

    // Get posted data
    $data  = $jinput->get('jform', null, 'raw');
    $file  = $jinput->files->get('jform');

    // renaming the file
    $file_ext=explode('.',JFile::makeSafe($file['invoice']['name'])); // invoice - file handler name
    $filename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . strtolower(end($file_ext));
    // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
    if ( $filename != '' ) {

        // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
        $filepath = JPath::clean( JPATH_ROOT."/media/your_component_name/files/". $filename );

        // Move the uploaded file.
        if (JFile::upload( $file['invoice']['tmp_name'], $filepath )) {
              echo "success :)";
        } else {
              echo "failed :(";
        }

        $data['name'] =  $filename ; // getting file name
        $data['path'] =  $filepath ; // getting file path
        $data['size'] =  $file['invoice']['size'] ; // getting file size
    }
    JRequest::setVar('jform', $data, 'post');
    $return = parent::save($data);
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 2.5 & 3 style:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$file= $input->files->get('file');

if(isset($file['name']))
{
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $file['name'] = strtolower(JFile::makeSafe($file['name']));
    $fileRelativePath = '/pathToTheRightFolder/'.$file['name'];
    $fileAbsolutePath = JPath::clean( JPATH_ROOT.$fileRelativePath);
    JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name'], $fileAbsolutePath );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

has a full upload sample.

> Little sample where admin choose the file type or all, enter the users to access the form upload. Folder to upload files in Joomla directory or with absolute path. Only selected users access the form upload.