# How to Save Uploaded File's Name on Database

Tags: php, file-upload, joomla, joomla2.5

Cont. - [Add File Uploader to Joomla Admin Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909324/add-file-uploader-to-joomla-admin-component/12909760#12909760)

I could able to upload file and save it on disk. But its not saving file name on the database.

How can i do it ?

Here is the controller -

```
class InvoiceManagerControllerInvoiceManager extends JControllerForm
{
    function save(){
        $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
        $path = JPATH_BASE;

        // Make the file name safe.
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        $file['name']['invoice'] = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['invoice']);

        // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
        if (isset($file['name']['invoice'])) {
            // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
            $filepath = JPath::clean($path. DS ."components". DS ."com_invoicemanager". DS ."files". DS .strtolower($file['name']['invoice']));
            // Move the uploaded file.
            JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name']['invoice'], $filepath );
        }

        return parent::save();
    }
}
```

Form field in XML -

```
<field name="invoice" type="file"/>
```

UPDATE:
worked after adding following lines taken from @Andras Gera code

```
$data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
$data['invoice'] = strtolower( $file['name']['invoice'] );

JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've ran into the same problem, maybe we can go forward together. Here is my codes:

/administrator/components/com_comp_name/models/forms/edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_gonewsletter/models/rules">
    <fieldset name="details">
        <field
            name="id"
            type="hidden"
        />
        <field
            name="title"
            type="text"
            label="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_TITLE_LABEL"
            description="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_TITLE_DESC"
            size="40"
            class="inputbox"
            required="true"
            default=""
        />
        <field
            name="date"
            type="calendar"
            label="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_DATE_LABEL"
            description="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_DATE_DESC"
            size="40"
            class="inputbox"
            required="true"
            default=""
            format="%Y-%m-%d"
        />
        <field
            name="published"
            type="list"
            label="JSTATUS"
            description="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_PUBLISHED_DESC"
            class="inputbox"
            size="1"
            default="0">
            <option
                value="1">JPUBLISHED</option>
            <option
                value="0">JUNPUBLISHED</option>
        </field>
        <field
            type="file"
            name="pdf_file"
            label="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_FILE_LABEL"
            default=""
            description="COM_GONEWSLETTER_EDIT_FILE_DESC"
            size="40"
            accept="application/pdf"
            class="fileuploader"
        />
        <field
            name="file"
            type="hidden"
        />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and
/administrator/components/com_comp_name/controllers/edit.php

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controllerform library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');

/**
 * GoNewsletter Controller
 */
class GoNewsletterControllerEdit extends JControllerForm
{
    function __construct($config = array()) {
        $this->view_list = 'List';
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    function save(){
        // ---------------------------- Uploading the file ---------------------
        // Neccesary libraries and variables
        jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.folder' );
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        $data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );

        // Create the gonewsleter folder if not exists in images folder
        if ( !JFolder::exists( JPATH_SITE . DS . "images" . DS . "gonewsletter" ) ) {
            JFolder::create( JPATH_SITE . DS . "images" . DS . "gonewsletter" );
        }

        // Get the file data array from the request.
        $file = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'files', 'array' );

        // Make the file name safe.
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['pdf_file']);

        // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
        if ( $filename != '' ) {
            // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
            $filepath = JPath::clean( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'images' . DS . 'gonewsletter' . DS . strtolower( $filename ) );

            // Move the uploaded file.
            JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name']['pdf_file'], $filepath );
            // Change $data['file'] value before save into the database 
            $data['file'] = strtolower( $filename );
        }
        // ---------------------------- File Upload Ends ------------------------

        JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );

        return parent::save();
    }

}
```

If you print out the $data before send it to parent::save($data) it contains the right fields you want to save, but it doesn't. I tried to use an input type=text instead of type=file and it saves correctly.

I tried another way like: input type=file and name=pdf_file, after then I added a hidden field name=file default="". And then I've set up this hidden field value to filename without success. Maybe I was doing something wrong. Keep continue to figure out something.

Comment: I think we should pass back the changed $data to POST method, because the parent::save() goes back to the system save(). Somehow if I add $data to save() function it doesn't get it well. Saves everything but only the file field is empty in the DB.

Comment: did you find anyway to do it ?

Comment: Yes, it solved! Thanks for Irfan to mention setVar function. He's solution doesn't work because it creates an another record instead of putting the needed variable into jform array in $_REQUEST array.
My solution is overriding the jform variable.

Comment: I'll finalize the code above to make it better. At this stage you'll lose the file variable when you edit the record.

Comment: It's fixed. Check xml and php code carefully. I've added a hidden field to keep the original file name when you edit other parts of the form. When you have selected a new file then replaces it. There is more to be fixed but I hope it helps a lot to go forward. Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot :) is working now. had to add following lines             $data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
            $data['invoice'] = strtolower( $file['name']['invoice'] );

            JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `move_uploaded_file()` function

Comment: File is successfully saved on the disk. I just need to store its name on database after upload.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //import joomlas filesystem functions, we will do all the filewriting with joomlas functions
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

      //this is the name of the field in the html form, filedata is the default name for swfupload
    $fieldName = 'Filedata';

        //the name of the file in PHP's temp directory that we are going to move to our folder
        $fileTemp = $_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name'];


        //always use constants when making file paths, to avoid the possibilty of remote file inclusion
        $uploadPath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'path'.DS.'path'.DS.$fileName;

        if(!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)) 
        {
                echo JText::_( 'ERROR MOVING FILE' );
                return;
        }
        else
        {
         //Updating the db with the $fileName.
         $db =& JFactory::getDBO();   
         $query = $db->getQuery(true);
         $query->update($db->nameQuote(TABLE_PREFIX.'table_name'));
         $query->set($column.' = '.$db->quote($fileName));
         $query->where($db->nameQuote('id').'='.$db->quote($id));             
         $db->setQuery($query);
         $db->query(); 
         }
```

$column - db column name of the file
$fileName -  file name

Query is ran if the file is successfully uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Dasun, File uploading now ok. I'm stuck at updating the database :/

Comment: i did as you mentioned. but its not working :/ here is the file saving part in my component - http://pastebin.com/yKiiBigu .. replaced $column with $invoice which VARCHAR in my table. var_dump of $db - http://pastebin.com/MyCdKrAB

Comment: you are missing the if statement of the JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath). Please refer the eg correctly and make changes to your code. If you come across any question please ask.

Comment: hmm i think issue comes from query. $column ($invoice in my case) is not defined. and the $id.

Comment: here is the modified code - http://pastebin.com/ytRLEJJZ var_dump of $db -http://pastebin.com/JqJnQMZk

Comment: everything seems fine. echo $query;die(); before $db->query(); and check whether the question is correct. try to run the query in mysql and see.(make sure you replace #_ with the db_prefix)

Comment: #__ automatically puts db prefix right ? $query->update($db->nameQuote('#__invoicemanager'));

Comment: here is the query - UPDATE `#__invoicemanager` SET = 'bg.png' WHERE `id`=''

Comment: did you try running the query ? post the result or the error here

Answer (score 1):

set filename in request variable as it's now a $_FILES variable

```
JRequest::setVar('jform[invoice]',$file['name']['invoice'] );
```

//full code

```
   class InvoiceManagerControllerInvoiceManager extends JControllerForm
    {
        function save(){
            $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
            $path = JPATH_BASE;

            // Make the file name safe.
            jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
            $file['name']['invoice'] = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['invoice']);

            // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
            if (isset($file['name']['invoice'])) {
                // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
                $filepath = JPath::clean($path. DS ."components". DS ."com_invoicemanager". DS ."files". DS .strtolower($file['name']['invoice']));
                // Move the uploaded file.
                JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name']['invoice'], $filepath );

                JRequest::setVar('jform[invoice]',$file['name']['invoice'] );
            }



            return parent::save();
        }

}
```

Comment: @ChamingaD: Test this-> JRequest::setVar('column','test' );If this works than there are some naming problem

Comment: @ChamingaD:what is the column name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18164/discussion-between-irfan-and-chamingad)

Answer (score 0):

On joomla 3.2.x, I have to override save function of my model class to save the uploaded file name to db, like this

```
public function save($data){
  $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;       
  $files = $input->files->get('jform');
  $fieldName = 'thumbnail';
  $data['thumbnail'] = $files[$fieldName]['name'];              
  return parent::save($data);
}
```