# Joomla set `file` field value after save

Tags: php, mysql, file, joomla, upload

For my backend component i need able upload image for my items. It all works fine, i add field for image:

```
<field
    type="file"
    name="category_image"
    accept="image/*"
    label="COM_SKYCATALOG_ITEM_CATEGORY_IMAGE_LABEL"
    directory=""
    preview="false"
/>
```

and then update `save()` method to control upload:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$files = $jinput->files->get('jform');      

$fileinfo =pathinfo($files['category_image']['name']);

$ext = $fileinfo['extension'];
$filename = time().".$ext";     

$tmp_file = $files['category_image']['tmp_name'];

$dest = "../media/com_xxxxx/upload/".$filename;

if (JFile::upload($tmp_file, $dest)) {
      // successed :)
} else {              
     // failed :(
echo "FAAAIL!!!";
die();
}
```

When i choose file and save item, file uploaded to folder, but then category image field is empty. And also field for category_image in mysql table did not updated, but when i use `media` field type it works fine.

What is possible wrong here?

I did not like media manager it to slow to work with.

Comment: Ok, i find partial solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927464/how-to-save-uploaded-files-name-on-database now it saves in db uploaded file name, but still did not load it when i open item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve this problem. You cant set value of `input` tag with `file` type, because of security reasons. I mean you can set `value` attribute but field wil displayed as blank.

So i just create a custom field like this:

```
class JFormFieldSkyupload extends JFormField
{
    /**
     * The field type.
     *
     * @var         string
     */
    protected $type = 'Skyupload';

    /**
     * Method to get a list of options for a list input.
     *
     * @return  array  An array of JHtml options.
     */
    public function getInput() {
        return '<div class="filename_labe">'.$this->value.'</div><input name="'.$this->name.'" id="'.$this->id.'" accept="image/*" aria-invalid="false" type="file" value="'.$this->value.'">';
        // code that returns HTML that will be shown as the form field
    }

}
```

And also i made some changes in upload code, so even if no new file selected i am able to save form without error:

```
if ($files['category_image']['name']!="")
{
    $fileinfo =pathinfo($files['category_image']['name']);

    $ext = JFile::getExt($files['category_image']['name']);
    $filename = time().".$ext";

    $tmp_file = $files['category_image']['tmp_name'];

    $dest = "../media/com_skycatalog/upload/".$filename;

    if (JFile::upload($tmp_file, $dest)) {
    // successed :)
    } else {                  
    // failed :(
    echo "FAAAIL!!!";
    die();      
    }        

$data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
$data['category_image'] = strtolower( $filename );
JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );
```

}

Now it will update file name in DB only if i upload new file.